# pip install optional dependencies with zsh

Tags: pip, zsh

I have a section of optional dependencies called `test` inside my pyproject.toml file:

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pylint",
    "pytest",
]
```

I install these for development and testing, but they aren't real dependencies of my package.

From bash I would include these like

```
pip install .[test]
```

but from zsh I get a message like `no matches found: .[test]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bzsh%5D+no+matches+found

Comment: `pip install '.[test]'`